# Sharing Set issue

Tags: sharing-sets

I am using sharing sets in our Napili Community to expose Cases to our users.

The Access Granted to "Manager" user accounts on the Case object:

```
User:Account = Case:Account.Parent
```

This seems to be working great in all but 1 situation. I have 2 scenarios that are exactly the same and the rule works in one but not the other. An account with no parent has a community user using the rule and it shows Cases in their account and all child accounts. I have another community user in an account with no parent that returns no cases for the account their user is part of or child accounts...

Anyone have any idea what might be causing the issue? I have tried using debug logs on the trouble user with no luck to try and find the query used in the sharing set.